# Possible File Search Memory Leak Eclipse 2019-03 v4.11

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse `Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0) Build id: 20190314-1200`. My Java version is `8u45`. I am on a Windows 10 machine.

I am having issues using the `Search -> File` search. If you do a search then close it and start another search anytime soon, the progress gets stuck at 98% and loops endlessly searching. I have had this happen searching even just once. This issue starts racking up CPU usage like crazy and in certain instances has grabbed up to 90% of my CPU usage. Trying to cancel the request in the `Progress` tab causes an instant crash. This has crashed my session and my computer. There seems to be a leak once you close the Search tab. I have verified with a colleague that this happens on his machine as well.

Is there a fix out there I can get a hold of? I am unable to find anything on Eclipse's bug page.

Comment: That sounds similar to [this Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=541178), which was a few months before your version (4.9/4.10). The user was asked to verify with a newer build, but there are no other updates.

Comment: @PaulT. that sounds nearly exactly the issue I am having.. man that sucks it's still out in the wild

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to 2019-06, which was released this past Wednesday, 19 Jun 2019.

I don't know if they have a fix to that particular problem, but if you're going to submit a bug report, best to do it against the latest release.

I upgraded my 2019-03 install by:

- Navigate to Help->Install New Software...
- Click Add
- Enter "Eclipse 2019-06" for the Name
- Enter "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-06" for the Location
- Click Add to dismiss
- Click Cancel on the "Available Software" form to get back to the main eclipse window
- Help->Check for Updates

It took a while to update, maybe 30 minutes.

Comment: As I am working in a business environment, we can't update versions of our IDEs without following procedure and that takes a while. We just went to 2019-03. We went from Mars to 2019-03, and it worked perfectly fine then.

Comment: @SovietFrontier It is dangerous and therefore not professional to use outdated software. You should at least be able, to test if the issue is still reproducible in Eclipse 2019-06. If it is fixed in Eclipse 2019-06, then you should follow the procedure.